# Silverlight behavior on different IE versions

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, silverlight

I am facing next problem:

1) My application on startup gets the list of items from backend and displays them - it works fine in all browsers and all versions.

**The problem appears on page Refresh**

When i refresh the page and application restarts on IE 8 list of items from backend is being displayed, but in IE 10 the application hangs up.

Any suggestion where should i start diggin this?